# How can I define a 3d array from a 2d array that depends on a parameter?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a matrix with 2 dimensions

```
M = np.array([[0.5+t, 1, 1],
              [0.5, 0.5, t],
              [0.5, 1-t, 0.5]])
```

I want to compute some properties of this matrix for several values of $t$. I could do it witn a for loop but I was wondering if there's a way of doing it without a loop. For example creating a 3d array where every slide of that array is a 2d array containg the matrix M for a given t.

The loop implementation will we something like this.

```
import numpy as np

def M(t: float):
    return np.array([[0.5+t, 1, 1], [0.5, 0.5, t], [0.5, 1-t, 0.5]])

t_vec = np.linspace(0, 1, num=100)

norm = np.zeros_like(t_vec)
for i, t in enumerate(t_vec):
    matrix = M(t)
    norm[i] = np.linalg.norm(matrix)
```

In this case I wanted to compute the 2 norm of the matrix an store all the values in an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend to use 2 arrays, one for M, one for `t`:

```
M = np.array([[0.5, 1.0, 1.0],
              [0.5, 0.5, 0.0],
              [0.5, 1.0, 0.5]])
t =  np.array([[1,  0, 0],
               [0,  0, 1],
               [0, -1, 0]])
```

Then:

```
M+t

M+t*2

# etc.
```

Or, in a vectorial way:

```
t_vec = np.linspace(0, 1, num=100)

out = M+t*t_vec[:,None,None]

norm = np.linalg.norm(M, axis=(1, 2))
```

Comment: ```t``` being a ```float``` (at the question), and ```t``` being an ```array``` (at your answer) confuses me

Comment: @CarlosAdir no you want `t` to be a **variable** in your process, which is what this code is doing. After you compute `t*x` where `x` is your increment, then you have the updated `t` for this step

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I want!! 
But I have a question.

Is it better to define the total matrix as a sum of two matrices rather than with a function?

I always get confuse by the use of `np.newaxis` (I know is the same as `None`) but I never know where to use it.

Comment: @mozway The main point I say is: changing the variable name in certain context (in the question) may cause confusion and decreases code readability. There are many variables names, such as ```T``` to distinguish of ```t```. In math, upper-case letters often represent matrix (like in the question, ```M``` is a matrix).

Comment: @mozway
I missclicked and post the comment withou questions hahaha.

Comment: I think it makes more sense to use matrices/ndarrrays rather than functions and let numpy handle the dimensions, it will also be more efficient ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can create base matrix without `t` values and then add `t` values 'mask' multiplied by the values you want to use. For example:

```
M_base = np.array(
    [[0.5, 1,   1  ],
     [0.5, 0.5, 0  ],
     [0.5, 1,   0.5]])
t = np.array(
    [[ 1,  0,  0],
     [ 0,  0,  1],
     [ 0, -1,  0]])

t_values = np.linspace(0, 1, num=100)

M = M_base + t*t_values[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]

norm = np.linalg.norm(M, axis=(1, 2))
```

Comment: Looks like we have globally the same approach, +1

Comment: @mozway Yeah, those are almost the same.

Answer (score 1):

The others answers do what you want to do. I put this answer only to have a faster way.

Let's say you have two matrix:

```py
N = np.array([[0.5, 1.0, 1.0],
              [0.5, 0.5, 0.0],
              [0.5, 1.0, 0.5]])
T = np.array([[1,  0, 0],
              [0,  0, 1],
              [0, -1, 0]])
```

Then, for given `t`, `M = N + t * T`.

The `numpy.linalg.norm(M)` can be described as `numpy.sqrt(numpy.sum(M**2))`. Therefore, to compute the norm for many `t` I would do:

```py
t_vec = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
# Once M**2 = (N+t*T)**2 = N**2 + 2*t * N*T + t**2 * T**2
# norm(M) = np.sqrt(M**2) = np.sqrt(N**2 + 2*t * N*T + t**2 * T**2)
sumN2 = np.linalg.norm(N)**2
sumT2 = np.linalg.norm(T)**2
sumNT = np.sum(N*T)
norm = np.sqrt(sumN2 + 2*t_vec * sumNT + t_vec**2 * sumT2)
```

Comment: I checked that and its not faster. My solution got
`37 µs ± 226 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)`
while yours
`40.4 µs ± 1.52 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)`.

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. I got almost the same proportion as you: yours ```35.5 µs ± 2002 ns``` and mine ```39.8 µs ± 2559 ns``` with ```10,000``` loops and ```100``` runs. I thought it would be faster by treating scalars with ```t_vec``` than taking the norm of a big array.

Comment: It has better time complexity but `100` values are just too few. For `10000` the results are: `439 µs ± 11.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)` and `72.5 µs ± 946 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)`, so your solution is about 6 times faster.